# How to detect and display all key elements of a object within a JObject?

Tags: c#, json, list, loops, object

I'm trying to detect and display all the key elements of a object within a JObject, for example with this JSON response:

```
{
"url": "www.test.nl/test.php",
"time": "2019-06-05 11:37:40",
"stringvalue": "otherValue1",
"intvalue": 433,
"array": [
    "value1": "35",
    "value2": "36",
    "value3": "37",
],
"otherObject1": {
    "name": "object1",
    "description": "A object type",
    "size": 120
}
}
```

As you can see there is an array named "array" and an object named "otherObject1".

In my backend im parsing this json response to a JObject:

[image]

Now I got the followng code that finds all the key elements and put these in a list:

```
List<string> keys = o2.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

[image]

This works fine but I also want the key values in my array and object located in the JObject in this list. The desired output would look like this:

```
[0] -> "url"
[1] -> "time"
[2] -> "stringvalue"
[3] -> "intvalue"
[4] -> "value1"        <-- of array
[5] -> "value2"        <-- of array
[6] -> "value3"        <-- of array
[7] -> "name"          <-- of object
[8] -> "description"   <-- of object
[9] -> "size"          <-- of object
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would be the desired behavior if `OtherObject1` contained a key of name "url"? In other words: You wouldn't care for duplicate key names?

Comment: I do care for duplicatie keys. Maybe a correct solution for that is to add the objectname + keyname to the list? So in thie case : "OtherObject1Key"?

Comment: Well, that's up to you, how you want it to be handled. I just wondered if it matters and if you had thought about it. The thing about the prefix is: How would you keep a nested key and a "root" key apart programmatically? The human eye would probably see that there is the "OtherObject1Key" Key and other Keys that are prefixed with this. But would your program?

Comment: Also how are you going to handle array of objects?

Comment: can you not make a wrapper that appends to that list you got the contents of any arrays, other objects..

Comment: I'm not sure how to handle an array of objects, first of all im trying to get the key values of the object or array within the JObject.